# Which is correct “no one does” or “no one do”?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

If I said that I don't like bad people and someone replies, should he say

no one does
or
no one do ?

If both are correct then which one is better or more frequently said?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"no one do" is incorrect in standard US English. "No one" is singular, and so the singular form "does" is required.

"Do" is the plural form, and "does" is the singular form of the verb "to do". "He does it, but they do it." Strictly speaking, these are the third-person plural and singular forms, respectively.

Comment: so what it's Plural ?

Comment: @Mina "Do" is the plural form, and "does" is the singular form of 'to do" -- "He does it, but they do it" Strictly speaking, the third-person plural and singular forms.

Comment: can you give me an example using the one that is in the question ?

Comment: so it should be everybody  don't ?

Comment: @Minia, no it should be "everybody does not" or "everybody doesn't".  The workd "everybody" (and also "everyone") takes a singular. Yes it designates multiple people, but it treats therm one at a tiem, and it takes singular forms, not plural forms. "Everybody does this" not "everybody do this".

Comment: so what it's plural  form of everybody ?